# Split sequences in fasta file

Tags: python, split, fasta

I use fasta file format,and I want to extract just sequences from it without **ids**, and split the sequences, I write this code

```
    outfile=open('output.txt','r')
    for line in open('sequences.fasta')
        if line[0]==">":
           continue
           outfile.write(line)
```

This step create a text file witch contains sequences, it gives:

```
    AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
    CCGCCTCGGGAGCGTCCATGGCGGGTTTGAACCTCTAGCCCGGCGCAGTTTGGGCGCCAAGCCATATGAA
    AGCATCACCGGCGAATGGCATTGTCTTCCCCAAAACCCGGAGCGGCGGCGTGCTGTCGCGTGCCCAATGA

    CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGTTGAGACAACAGAATATATGATCGAGTG
    AATCTGGAGGACCTGTGGTAACTCAGCTCGTCGTGGCACTGCTTTTGTCGTGACCCTGCTTTGTTGTTGG
    GCCTCCTCAAGAGCTTTCATGGCAGGTTTGAACTTTAGTACGGTGCAGTTTGCGCCAAGTCATATAAAGC

    CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGTTGAGACAGCAGAACATACGATCGAGTG
     AATCCGGAGGACCCGTGGTTACACGGCTCACCGTGGCTTTGCTCTCGTGGTGAACCCGGTTTGCGACCGG
     GCCGCCTCGGGAACTTTCATGGCGGGTTTGAACGTCTAGCGCGGCGCAGTTTGCGCCAAGTCATATGGAG
     ....
```

Then, I want to split each sequence, to obtain sub-sequences contains three bases like "CGT", I put this code:

```
    for line in open('f:/output.txt', 'r'):
    seq=line.strip()
        [seq[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(seq), 3)]
```

**This gives:**

```
    ['CGT', 'AAC', 'AAG', 'GTT', 'TCC', 'GTA', 'GGT', 'GAA', 'CCT', 'GCG', 'GAA',        'GGA', 'TCA', 'TTG', 'ATG', 'AGA', 'CCG', 'TGG', 'AAT', 'AAA', 'CGA', 'TCG',     'AGT', 'G']

    ['AAT', 'CCG', 'GAG', 'GAC', 'CGG', 'TGT', 'ACT', 'CAG', 'CTC', 'ACC', 'GGG','GGC', 'ATT', 'GCT', 'CCC', 'GTG', 'GTG', 'ACC', 'CTG', 'ATT', 'TGT', 'TGT', 'TGG', 'G']
    ['CCG', 'CCT', 'CGG', 'GAG', 'CGT', 'CCA', 'TGG', 'CGG', 'GTT', 'TGA', 'ACC', 'TCT', 'AGC', 'CCG', 'GCG', 'CAG', 'TTT', 'GGG', 'CGC', 'CAA', 'GCC', 'ATA', 'TGA', 'A']
```

for me, I want to split the sequences in groups, each group contain three  sequences and its length is 9 (nine baseses) , then I split each sequence to sub-sequences of three bases , so I must know the length of each sequences.

**For example**

```
    CGTAACAAG 
    AATCCGGAG 
    CCGCCTCGG
```

then, I apply some operations on this sub-sequences, and I do the same steps on all the length of the sequences.

can some one help me to do this, and rectify my code

Answer (score 0):

[BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) is good for this, and if you have more bioinformatics questions I encourage you to check out [BioStars.](http://www.biostars.org/)

Do you mean to do something like this?

```
outfile=open('outf','w')
for line in open('input'):
    if line[0]==">":
       outfile.write('\n')
    else:
        outfile.write(line.strip())

outfile.close()

all_codons=[]
for line in open('outf', 'r'):
    seq=line.strip()
    codons = [seq[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(seq), 3) if len(seq[i:i+3])==3]
    all_codons.append(codons)

all_tripeptides = []
for seq_line in all_codons:
    tripeptides = [''.join(seq_line[i:i+3]) for i in xrange(len(seq_line)) if len(seq_line[i:i+3])==3]
    all_tripeptides.append(tripeptides)
```

Comment: ok, thank you.Know  from the splited sequences I want to take three sequences its lengths is 9,I split the first sequence to 3 sub-sequences of three bases, so, from one sequences I obtain 3 sub-sequences, I di the same thing for the two other sequences.Then , I apply this function :                                                                def identical_segment(input_string):
 code={"a":0,"c":1,"g":2,"t":3}
 p=[code[i] for i in input_string]
 n=len(input_string)
 c=0
 for i, n in enumerate(range(n, 0, -1)):
  c +=p[i]*(4**(n-1))
  return c+1

Comment: I want to apply this function to each sub-sequences of th three sequences, then apply the same thing on all fasta file

Comment: So, the purpose is to obtain matrix, for example I take the first sub-sequence 'cct' and apply the function identical_segment() , it returns 24, the same thing for the rest 8 sub-sequences. So I obtain a matrix(3,3):

Comment: Sorry it's hard to understand what you're asking here, you should edit your original question with the code snippets you've posted.  Make sure you highlight them and press ctrl+K so that they are correctly formatted.

Comment: ok, I rewrite my question in details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767983/how-to-split-fasta-file