# How to split fasta file

Tags: python, split, fasta

This code is for extract and split sequences from fasta file

```
outfile=open('outf','w')
for line in open('input'):
      if line[0]==">":
         outfile.write('\n')
     else:
    outfile.write(line.strip())

   outfile.close()
 all_codons=[]
 for line in open('outf', 'r'):
     seq=line.strip()
     codons = [seq[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(seq), 3) if len(seq[i:i+3])==3]
     all_codons.append(codons)
```

Then, from the splited sequences I want to take three sequences its lengths is 9( 9 bases) example:

```
    CGTAACAAG 
    AATCCGGAG 
    CCGCCTCGG
```

I split the first sequence to 3 sub-sequences of three bases, so, from one sequences I obtain 3 sub-sequences, I do the same thing for the two other sequences.

Like this:

```
    CGT    AAC     AAG 
    AAT    CCG     GAG 
    CCG    CCT     CGG
```

example:

```
identical_segment('CGT')
```

I want to apply this function to each sub-sequences of th three sequences, then apply the same thing on all fasta file. So, the purpose is to obtain matrix, for example I take the first sub-sequence 'CGT' and apply the function identical_segment() , it returns 28, the same thing for the rest 8 sub-sequences. So I obtain a matrix(3,3):

```
28         2             3
4          23            35
23         4             27
```

What can I do?

Comment: you shouldn't post a new question to clarify an older one!  Just click the 'edit' button on your old question and add the information there.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code.

First, you only want certain lines in your file, throwing out others, then outputting the desired lines to a file. I'm not sure why the last step is needed. Direct processing of the lines is more efficient.

```
def processLines(inputname):
    all_codons=[]
    for line in open(inputname):
        if line[0]==">":
            seq=line.strip()
            codons = [seq[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(seq), 3) if
                      len(seq[i:i+3])==3]
        all_codons.append(codons)
    return all_codons
```

Also, every call to identical_segment will generates a dictionary that you use as mapping from str to scores. It may become expensive when number of calls scales. To avoid this, you can try two ways:

```
code={"a":0,"c":1,"g":2,"t":3} 
def identical_segment(input_string):
   .... # what you have written
```

or create a class whose instance contains the dictionary.

In order to process multiple files, do:

```
output = [processLines(filename) for filename in filenames]
# filenames is an iterable
```

or if you want to map the input name to output:

```
outputDict = {filename: processLines(filename) for 
              filename in filenames}
```

After all, call your analyzing function on each output and write them to an output file.

To summarize what you should pick up in this post:

1. Output files may not be the best option, since file IO is expensive. If you write it to some file, it means you have to read it in again, which is doubly expensive.
2. The same object should not be created over and over again. Proofread your code to make sure this does not happen.
3. Partition your main task into several small tasks, then think of a simple and intuitive way for each task to start with. In this example, we have processfiles-> analysis-> output_result
4. Comprehension is a useful way to iterate things in Python, and it's more readable. You can search for list comprehension and dictionary comprehension to learn more.

Try something out yourself. I'll be more than happy to read your improved code here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) to extract the nucleotide sequences from your fasta file. Using this package,

```
from Bio import AlignIO

for record in AlignIO.parse('filename.fasta', 'fasta'):
    print record.id, record.seq

# or store in a new file
seqs = []
for record in AlignIO.parse('filename.fasta', 'fasta'):
    seqs.append(record.seq + '\n')

with open(outfile, 'w') as out:
    out.writelines(seqs)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when each sequence is of a different length, eg `ValueError: Sequences must all be the same length`